# Changing the coordinate system of nodes, without carrying the changes

Tags: opengl, matrix, rendering, linear-algebra, skeletal-animation

I am loading 3D models from multiple formats, each possibly with its own coordinate system.

Transforming them so that they are all in the same coordinate system is easy.

The issue is when I try to attach one model to another, when both are of the same format.
Because they were already in the same coordinate system, the transformation that changes them to whatever shared coordinate system will be applied twice to the child.

I could make specific code for each format, and every time I want to attach something to another something, check formats, and ughhhh.

My current node structure is very generic, and I wonder if there is a generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once the models are in your program, they should no longer be in "its own coordinate system." Pick a convention and stick to it.

If you're loading models that have a different convention, that's fine. But you transform *their vertices* after loading them. So there's no need to fiddle around with coordinate system transforms in your scene graph.

Comment: The models I am loading indeed have different conventions. Changing the vertices themselves at load time isn't the issue, really, it's far more tedious to change all of the animation data that is spread all over. Another format also uses packed vertices, so I do not interact with them whatsoever outside of the shaders.

Comment: @user2503048: Are... are you *really* saying that you could fix the problem, but don't want to?

Comment: I am asking if there is a more elegant and generic way to fix it.